# Can XP be done correctly without Pair Programming?

Tags: extreme-programming

I read that eXtreme Programming isn't XP, if there's no Pair Programming.  But is there something inherit in XP that requires Pair Programming other than philosophy, if other types of quality engineering guideline are followed (maybe TDD, for example.)

I understand what Pair Programming is, read lots on it, no never tried it, and I'm not trying to knock Paired Programming, nor trying to get convinced for it.  I only wanted to know if XP can be useful without it.  There was much I liked about XP.

Answer (score 4):

Many tools can be useful without utilizing all the facets; however, the price is often reductions in benefits such as effectiveness, efficiency, and quality or an increase in costs and risks.  One should not call something what it isn't.

If one removes the handle from a hammer, it may still *work* for nailing; however it certainly won't be as effective or efficient, and will probably result in lower quality with a higher possibility of injury.  Anyone calling it a hammer would be misleading others which would result in further misunderstandings and complications.

[Pair Programming](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/pair.html) is a rule in eXtreme Programming. By excluding that facet the benefits are reduced and risks are increased.  Calling it is XP would be dishonesty.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer you in a different way.

Agile, PMP, TOGAF, COBIT and all of the frameworks must be tailored according to the company's culture.

There is no rule says that you need to follow the book 100%.

I hope that this is what you needed to know.